# React : How to execute a method every 10s?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I woudlike to run my method "getNumber" every 10s for example How can I do this ?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          web3: '',
        }

        this.getNumber = this.getNumbert.bind(this);
        
      }

getNumber(){
       let number = 0;
       number = number + 1;
      }
```

Comment: have you tried `setInterval` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some advice:

- use native JS function `setInterval()` to run a given function every x milliseconds
- you will need to store the number in state if you want to trigger a re-render every time it changes.

**Working example:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      web3: "",
      number: 0
    };
    this.getNumber = this.getNumber.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.getNumber, 10000);
  }

  getNumber() {
    this.setState({ number: this.state.number + 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Number: {this.state.number}</div>
        <span>This will update every 10 seconds</span>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-snow-w4tlf?file=/src/App.js:0-542)

Answer (score 0):

Inside `componentDidMount` you can start a `setInterval` - which takes 2 params, a method to invoke, and a time (in ms) for it to wait before running again.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
    let number = 0;
    number = number + 1;
  }, 10000)
}
```

Although this would currently set `number` back to 0 every 10 seconds. You'd want to use a number that is saved as state.

Comment: thank you ! and if I want just to call getNumber() function ?

Comment: Instead of passing an arrow function to `setInterval` you can just do `setInterval(getNumber, 10000)`. Don't add the `()` to the end of getNumber when passing it in, you only want to pass a reference so the function knows what to invoke - not invoke it yourself.